# Having two values for same index in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, floating-point

I am trying to assign a String and a float to a single array index. For example -

```
New England 98 
Tennessee 58.3

array[0] should store New England and the floating point number 98
array[1] should store Tennessee and the floating point number 58.3
```

and so on. 
My questions is how do I store a String object and float at the same index in an array in Java. I thought about pairing them like (key,value) and then store it to one index but I have no idea how to do so

Any ideas how I can assign these two data types to same index?

Comment: Have you considered using 2 dimensional arrays?

Comment: Yes, But the problem is I want to store both data types in the same array index rather than 2D array.

Comment: Java is an **Object-Oriented** language. *Use it*. Create a class with your two values, and store instances of the class in the list.

Comment: Yes, I can create another class with two separate fields. However, I was wondering if there is a way to store (String, float) in a pair in one array index.

Comment: Not in a simple array. You could use a Map or a 2D array to achieve something similar to what you want.

Comment: EASY! you can convert the float to a string, and add it to the first string with some separator character (eg. "Tennessee~58.3"), Then when you access them you take substring before and after the ~ to get your data back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a class named `A`,and it has two fields like this:

```
public class A{
    private String str;
    private float num;
}
```

So you can create an array which type is `A[]`,when you add an element to it,call A's constructor and save it.

Comment: OP said `String`, not `Object`.

Comment: @Andreas,yes,thanks for your suggestion,String will be more suitable,answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could use an HashMap.

```
 Map<String, float> myMap = new HashMap<>();

   // add your pair
   myMap.put("New England", 98);
   myMap.put("Tennessee", 58.3);
   myMap.put("etc", 99.99);

   // get value for Tennessee
   float val = (float)myMap.get("Tennessee");  //58.3

   //This will overide the value associated with the key
   myMap.put("Tennessee", 41.12);

   // get value for Tennessee
   float val2 = (float)myMap.get("Tennessee");  //41.12
```

If there is a chance that someday you have more than a pair of values, you should definitely create a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with two attributes (String str and float f).Then you need to create a array of objects of class above.Thus you can assign a String and a float to a singlw array index.